# restrict the user from entering a duplicate IDitem

Tags: java, swing

so i have a data structure  project assignment , that i need to create singly linked list and implement a swing + exception handling concept.
I create a super market list item , but i am having a problem of restricting the user from entering  duplicate ID-item , when user enters the duplicate it id , i wish to have a message " duplicate ID not allowed  "
here is my code  in the "frame" class

```
if(B==b11)
        try
    {
         al1.AddItem(Integer.parseInt(t1.getText()),t2.getText(),Integer.parseInt(t4.getText()),Double.parseDouble(t5.getText()));
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Added");
    }
    catch(Exception x){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(panel,"Wrong input ,please renter the fields ", "Warning",
           JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);

    };
```

and this is my code in the "Node process" class

```
    public void AddItem(int ID, String Name, int Q, double P)
        {
    if(head==null)

    head=tail=new  project6(ID,Name,Q,P,head);
        else
        {
              project6 pred, tmp;
            for(pred = head, tmp = head.next; tmp != null && ID > tmp.ProductID; pred = pred.next, tmp = tmp.next);
            if(tmp != null)
            pred.next = new   project6(ID,Name,Q,P,tmp);
            else
            tail.next = tail = new   project6(ID,Name,Q,P, null);


        }
}
```

Comment: can u maintain another Set<Integer>  idSet of IDs? so before you Add item , you can do an idSet.contains(currentID) and if true , then display the error message ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are adding elements to a [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html), you can use the `contains()` method; if not, you should write a comparable method that [traverses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list#Linked_list_operations) your `Node` data structure.

Alternatively, you might want to consider adding elements to a [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html), which precludes duplicates. `TreeSet` may a good concrete implementation, as it remains ordered. The `add()` implementation returns `false` if the "set already contains the element." You can use that information to throw a suitable exception.